# edit wpf code that refers to a resource

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to edit a source code in c#
forms writes with  WPF, and in them don't declare 
properties directly but use from references in below
I placed some lines from a WPF form.

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label>
            <LocText ResourceIdentifierKey="CustomerName" Suffix=":"/>
        </Label>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="200" Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <Label>
            <LocText ResourceIdentifierKey="GroupCode" Suffix=":"/>
        </Label>
        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="150" Text="{Binding       GroupCode,Mode=TwoWay}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding GroupCodes}" IsEditable="True"/>
        <Label>
            <LocText ResourceIdentifierKey="PhoneNumber" Suffix=":"/>
        </Label>
        <Common:MaskedTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="100" InputMask="{Binding PhoneNumberInputMask}"
             PromptChar=" " UnmaskedText="{Binding PhoneNumber, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" />
        <Label>
            <LocText ResourceIdentifierKey="Address" Suffix=":"/>
        </Label>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="200" MinHeight="55" Text="{Binding Address}"
             AcceptsReturn="True" />
        <Label>
            <LocText ResourceIdentifierKey="Note" Suffix=":"/>
        </Label>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="200" MinHeight="55" Text="{Binding Note}"
             AcceptsReturn="True" />
        <CheckBox Margin="0,5,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding InternalAccount}">
            <LocText ResourceIdentifierKey="InternalAccount"/>
        </CheckBox>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10" MinWidth="70" Content="{Binding SaveCommand.Caption}"
             Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
        <Label Content="{Binding Error}" Foreground="Red" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

how can I edit an attribute?

for example, I want to change the content of a Lable.

Comment: What is the question? how to edit source code? with a keyboard :) Or how to let user editing some text instead of just displaying it? Or smth other?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know what you're asking - if you want to edit the source code, just load the file in Visual Studio and type.

If you want to change the content of a Label at runtime, there are two approaches.

One is to use Binding to hook up the label to a property on the DataContext object associated with your form/usercontrol.

The other would be to give the label an actual name:

```
<Label x:Name="showAccountError Foreground="Red"/>
```

and then you can set the content in code:

```
showAccountError.Content = "Sample error";
```